# How to set additionalText for items of MultiComboBox

Tags: sapui5

I'd like to add `additionalText` property while using [`sap.m.MultiComboBox`](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.MultiComboBox.html). My view looks as follows:

```
<MultiComboBox items="{/list}" width="17rem" >
    <core:ListItem key="{Name}" text="{Name}" additionalText="{Price}" />
</MultiComboBox>
```

But this doesn't seem to work as [ListItem](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.core.ListItem.html) is not an aggregation for MultiComboBox.

Comment: It's now supported: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42013878/5846045. Just need to add `showSecondaryValues` to the MultiComboBox.

Answer (score 4):

### As of UI5 1.60

The control [`sap.m.MultiComboBox` now supports](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/commit/fbf721416619b462b1ba480e3995ab2d7a4ad534) the property `showSecondaryValues` which should be used together with `additionalText` in `<core:ListItem>`.

```xml
<MultiComboBox xmlns="sap.m" showSecondaryValues="true" items="{/ProductCollection}">
  <core:ListItem key="{ProductId}" text="{Name}" additionalText="{ProductId}" />
</MultiComboBox>
```

[**Sample: MultiComboBox - Two columns layout**](https://sdk.openui5.org/entity/sap.m.MultiComboBox/sample/sap.m.sample.MultiComboBoxTwoColumnsLayout)

[image: sap.m.MultiComboBox two columns showSecondaryValues additionalText]

---

### UI5 1.58 and below

The problem is that, initially, the control *Multi Combo Box* was not designed to display more than one attribute in the list. According to the [Fiori Design Guideline](https://experience.sap.com/fiori-design-web/multi-combobox/):

> **Do not use** the multi-combo box if you need to display more than one attribute.

I wouldn't suggest to invest much time to do any hack around this limitation making the app more error-prone and less maintainable. Instead, use an alternative control such as [*Select Dialog*](https://sdk.openui5.org/entity/sap.m.SelectDialog) with the option `multiSelect: true`.

The guideline also mentions [*Value Help Dialog*](https://experience.sap.com/fiori-design-web/multi-combobox/) as an option. But it's *currently* closed sourced and thus not available in OpenUI5 [**yet.**](https://groups.community.sap.com/t5/application-development/smart-controls-and-openui5/m-p/4723)

Answer (score 0):

Would concatenating the text property work for you? As you don't seem to be able to define a really additional text, a workaround should be something like this:

```
<MultiComboBox items="{/list}" width="17rem" >
    <core:Item key="{Name}" text="{Name}: {Price}" />
</MultiComboBox>
```

Comment: In this case, when the user selects any value, the whole thing gets displayed in MultiComboBox. As the space is limited, we just want to display the "Name".

Answer (score 0):

```
<ComboBox
            showSecondaryValues= "true"
            items="{
                path: '/ProductCollection',
                sorter: { path: 'Name' }
            }">
            <core:ListItem key="{ProductId}" text="{Name}" additionalText = {CurrencyCode}"/>
```

[refer this](https://openui5beta.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/sample/sap.m.sample.ComboBox2Columns/code)